# Libreoffice Base - Basic - How get data from csv file and put in the odb database?

Tags: libreoffice, radix, basic

I'm trying to built a macro in Libreoffice Basic that give form csv file some records and put them in an internal database built in libreoffice.

I remember that was possible in MSAccess but I have some difficult in Libreoffice Base.

the following line could use to create a connection with internal DB?

```
DatabaseContext = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
```

I found that examples

```
Dim DatabaseContext As Object
Dim DataSource As Object
Dim QueryDefinitions As Object
Dim QueryDefinition As Object
Dim I As Integer
 
DatabaseContext = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
DataSource = DatabaseContext.getByName("Customers")
QueryDefinitions = DataSource.getQueryDefinitions()
 
For I = 0 To QueryDefinitions.Count() - 1
  QueryDefinition = QueryDefinitions(I)
  MsgBox QueryDefinition.Name
Next I
```

but it seem no wroking. No result.
Just find a way to put what I rode on csv file inside DB

Answer (score 1):

it can be achieved by following the steps below

1.Open a libre base file

2.Open the csv file you want to import

3.Copy the contents of the csv, using e.g ctr+c (if using windows operating system)

4 Go back to the opened libre base file

5. Click on Tables tab on the left
6. On the list of tables pane, right click and choose paste
7. A Wizard dailog box will open
8. Under table name, enter the name of the table you want to store the imported data
9. Under options, choose definition and data

10 Click next at the bottom

11 You will see the column names from the CSV by the left

12. Select the columns you want to import and click the right arrow button in the middle, this will move the selected columns from the left side to the right side

13  Click next at the bottom

14  Next is options to retain or change the column names, field size etc

15  Click create at the bottom

16  You will be prompted to create a primary key field, choose yes

That's all the steps needed to import all data from a CSV file  into libre base file